# Nested SQL query made it hard to understand, what's going on?

Tags: sql-server, mysql

> Tables:

```
employee(eno,ename)

works_on(eno,pno,ename)

project(pno, project)

select ename from employee where eno in(
select eno from works_on where pno =(select * from project))
```

> what is the output ?
>
> a)Employee who works on all project.
>
> b)Employee who works one project .
>
> c) name of employee who works on more than one project.

Comment: What have you concluded so far? Nothing wrong with posting homework, but you need to put some effort into the problem

Comment: @Lennart I tried to run it on MySQL workbench created all the table with primary and foreign key reference. But that query didn't worked, the error says "Operand should contain 1 column(s)", until I changed " = " to " in " inside the first select as suggested by #DKramer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands this query:

```
select ename from employee where eno in(
select eno from works_on where pno =(select * from project))
```

Will return a 116 Error in SQL Server.

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1.  Only one expression can be specified in
>   the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Due to having a subquery with SELECT *, in the where clause. If you ammend this by selecting the PNO column from project.

```
select ename from employee where eno in(
select eno from works_on where pno = (select pno from project))
```

You will still (potentially) get an error depending on your actual dataset.

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This
>   is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or
>   when the subquery is used as an expression.

Assuming you intend to use the query as followed:

```
select ename from employee where eno in(
select eno from works_on where pno in (select pno from project))
```

You will get a list of employees that work on (a) project(s).